# Passing HTML to PHP parameters?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to pass HTML to the following function

```
$response = good_mail_using_mandrill($to,$subject,$body,$from_name,$from_email,$MandrilluserAPIKey,$SubAccountID );
```

At the moment $body takes the entire HTML content from a MySQL field and sends the API call to Mandrill.

What I find is that certain HTML goes through but others dont. I am not sure what tags in the HTML cause this failure. Are there any restrictions on what content can be sent in the $body variable?

This is driving me nuts. Mandrill says that they are receiving "null" content.

Is there a way to read the API call at delivery?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mandrill, but are you ensuring that you are adding line breaks into your body every 78 characters? The first thing that comes to my mind is some sort of protocol error resulting in the discarding of the data

Comment: If they say they're receiving null content, perhaps you should put a little debug line in like `if (is_null($body)) { yourLogFunction('Body was null!'); }` and monitor how often it may actually occur. It might be a problem at a higher level than this, e.g where `$body` is set

Comment: Thanks some helpful suggestions to go by. Will revert on how it goes..

Comment: It turns out that the HTML exported out of MailChimp is rejected by Mandrill unless you clean it up!